# How to randomly rename buttons. Java

Tags: java

I created a 10x10 grids for my battle ship game. all my buttons are being named as numbers, how ever I want them to be named from A1 to J10 in order and I cant get hol of how I need to do it.

```
public class Center_Panel extends JPanel {

    public Center_Panel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + +j));
         panel1.add(button);
         button.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            }});
         //GridCellP1 [i][j] = button;   
         }

         }
```

Comment: Where is the random in what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the char-datatype, you can use the `++` operator to traverse:

```
public Center_Panel() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    char c = 'A';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
           JButton button = new JButton(c + "" + j);
           panel1.add(button);
           button.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

               }});
           //GridCellP1 [i][j] = button;   
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `char` type values you add or subtract their ASCII values to change their value.

For instance,

```
char c = 'a';
c++;  // c now equals b
```

However, if you wan't to be able to access them by index you can do it two different ways.

**Way 1:**

Use an array to store all the values!

```
char[] array = {'a','b, 'c'...,'z'}

// now you can access by index
char c = array[3];
// c equals the value of d
```

**Way 2:**

Construct a method that outputs a char by position in the alphabet.

```
// starting number of the alphabet is 0 (because i'm a programmer.) :D
private char getChar(int value){
    return value + 65;
}
```

This link will help you with understanding the ASCII table.

http://www.asciitable.com/